# Return rows from a multidimensional array with same value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array and need to filter for specific rows.

Here's the contents of an sample array.

```
  $arr = array(
               array("id"=>1, "msisdn"=>10, "sc"=>8155),
               array("id"=>2, "msisdn"=>20, "sc"=>22020),
               array("id"=>3, "msisdn"=>10, "sc"=>8155), 
               array("id"=>4, "msisdn"=>10, "sc"=>8155), 
               array("id"=>5, "msisdn"=>20, "sc"=>22020), 
               array("id"=>6, "msisdn"=>30, "sc"=>22020) 
             );
```

How can I get just the rows where the value of `msisdn` is equal to 10, for example?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you're trying to do?
You mention an array and wanting to output multiple rows. What do you specifically want to output and what data do you have?

Comment: can you elaborate plese

Comment: would you like some filtering on that array? based on what?

Comment: would you like us to wipe your mouth after you finish eating? Perhaps pad you back so you can burp? a glass of water? something? :) Elaborate, or find a forum to ask your question ;)

Comment: here I want to return msisdn value=10 with id 1,3,4 i,e msisdn=>10 will return id=>1,id=>2,id=>4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? It will iterate through your array and you can search for a specific value and type.

I don't want to go into too much detail as your question isn't entirely clear.

```
function get_rows_by_type($array, $type, $val)
{
  $output = array();
  foreach ($array as $a) {
    if ($a[$type] === $val) {
      $output[] = $a;
    }
  }
  return $output;
}

var_dump (get_rows_by_type($arr, 'msisdn', 10));
```